# How to make an image in a <div> appear when you mouse over it?

Tags: html, mouseover

essentially the title. I don't know if this wording would work better, if you can make the entire  appear when mouse over that would be awesome.

Comment: :hover in the css will do it

Comment: this can help too: http://jsfiddle.net/johnpapa/XLWGb/light/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make a test image **invisible** on mouseover, from [here](http://forums.htmlhelp.com/index.php?showtopic=5991). Maybe swap the 'hidden' for 'visible' and vice versa?

```
<div id="test" name="test" onmouseover="document.getElementById('test_image').style.visibility= 'hidden';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('test_image').style.visibility= 'visible'">
<img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif" id="test_image">
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, I'm still new to this